# Play Framework 2.2.1 - Adding non-play Java Project as sub-project

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, subproject

I am trying to add a non-play Java project as a sub-project. The main project is a Play Java Application and the sub-project is in the same directory as the main-project. I am following instruction given [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/SBTSubProjects). My build.sbt looks like

```
import play.Project._

name := "main-project"

version := "1.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(javaJdbc, javaEbean)

playJavaSettings

lazy val mainProject = project.in(file("."))
    .aggregate(subProject)
    .depends(subProject)

lazy val subProject = project.in(file("../sub-projects/sub-project-1"))
```

Here is my directory structure

```
D:
|-- projects
|   |-- main-project
|   |-- sub-projects
|   |   |   |-- sub-project-1
|   |   |   |-- sub-project-2
```

When I try to compile the main project, I get the following error.

```
[info] Loading project definition from D:\projects\main-project\project
D:\projects\main-project\build.sbt:13: error: value depends is not a member of sbt.Project
possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value depends'?
.depends(subProject)
 ^
[error] sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

Comment: I've submitted a pull request to fix the broken documentation example: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/2453

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `dependsOn` not `depends`.

You should also point to both projects from the folder root:

```
name := "java-test"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

playJavaSettings

lazy val mainProject = project.in(file("."))
    .aggregate(subProject, playProject)
    .dependsOn(subProject, playProject)


lazy val subProject = project.in(file("sub-projects/sub-project-1"))

//play project depends on subProject...
lazy val playProject = project.in(file("play-project")).dependsOn(subProject)
```

Comment: It solves the error that I have posted. But the project still doesn't compile. I use a sub-project package in the main project and when I compile, it says, "package org.subproject.package does not exist". Are there further changes to be made in built.sbt?

Comment: if `playProject` needs something in `subProject` you'll need to define that dependency: `playProject = project.in(...).dependsOn(subProject)`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Doesn't work. I am getting the same error. Another thing that there is no "java-test". Just two project. Play project and another non-play project. The Play project uses classes from the non-play project. The non-play project is a standard eclipse project with no build.sbt.

Comment: I misunderstood - if the other project is not using sbt, you'll need to create the jar and either publish it to an Ivy repository or add the library to the `libs` folder of your sbt project. see the sbt docs on library dependencies: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Library-Dependencies.